# Coldfusion regex to generate slug

Tags: regex, function, coldfusion, slug

I have this function to generate slugs in Coldfusion:

```
<cffunction name="generateSlug" output="false" returnType="string">
    <cfargument name="str">
    <cfargument name="spacer" default="-">

    <cfset var ret = "" />

    <cfset str = lCase(trim(str)) />
    <cfset str = reReplace(str, "[àáâãäå]", "a", "all") />
    <cfset str = reReplace(str, "[èéêë]", "e", "all") />
    <cfset str = reReplace(str, "[ìíîï]", "i", "all") />
    <cfset str = reReplace(str, "[òóôö]", "o", "all") />
    <cfset str = reReplace(str, "[ùúûü]", "u", "all") />
    <cfset str = reReplace(str, "[ñ]", "n", "all") />
    <cfset str = reReplace(str, "[^a-z0-9-]", "#spacer#", "all") />
    <cfset ret = reReplace(str, "#spacer#+", "#spacer#", "all") />

    <cfif left(ret, 1) eq "#spacer#">
        <cfset ret = right(ret, len(ret)-1) />
    </cfif>
    <cfif right(ret, 1) eq "#spacer#">
        <cfset ret = left(ret, len(ret)-1) />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn ret />
</cffunction>
```

and then i am calling it using this:

```
<cfset stringToBeSlugged = "This is a string abcde àáâãäå èéêë ìíîï òóôö ùúûü ñ año ñññññññññññññ" />
<cfset slug = generateSlug(stringToBeSlugged) />
<cfoutput>#slug#</cfoutput>
```

But this is output me this slug:

this-is-a-string-abcde-a-a-a-a-a-a-e-e-e-e-i-i-i-i-o-o-o-o-u-u-u-u-n-a-no-n-n-n-n-n-n-n-n-n-n-n-n-n

it seems that all the accented characters are correctly replaced but this function is inserting a '-' after replacing them. Why?

Where is the error?

**PD**: i am expecting this **output**:

```
this-is-a-string-abcde-aaaaaa-eeee-iiii-oooo-uuuu-n-ano-nnnnnnnnnnnnn
```

Thanks.

Comment: what output you are expecting form the above function?

Comment: then remove `<cfif left(ret, 1) eq "#spacer#">
        <cfset ret = right(ret, len(ret)-1) />
    </cfif>
    <cfif right(ret, 1) eq "#spacer#">
        <cfset ret = left(ret, len(ret)-1) />
    </cfif>` part

Comment: i mimicked your example in python and I don't think there is need of that part if what you expect as output is correct

Comment: @rock321987 sorry but it is not working. Same output, not as expected :-(

Comment: working as it is on cf10,11 and 2016. Tested on trycf.com. http://trycf.com/gist/4f861b82a8c700e2d9dbefb896abb56e/acf?theme=monokai

Comment: Yes but not in cf8, that is the version of my server :-(

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  Specifically, output the str variable at the start of the function and then every time to do something to it.

Comment: *output the str variable at the start of the function* ... and after each replace to find out which reReplace statement is the issue. In other words, add some debugging code to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: not that it'll help, but i tried it on coldfusion 9 and it worked fine

Comment: What happens if you add another character to the replacement, like make `a` into `aA`? Just for debugging of course.

Comment: Look at my pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ZWudrrsN i am getting crazy with CF8 and i cannot upgrade my server...

Comment: Good example! For future reference, you might get weird results like that if the string is interpreted with a different/wrong encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you? (I've adapted a similar script that we use internally.)  I believe that we used this with ColdFusion 8 as we are still use it w/CF9.

```
<cffunction name="generateSlug" output="false" returnType="string">
    <cfargument name="str" default="">
    <cfargument name="spacer" default="-">
    <cfset var ret = replace(arguments.str,"'", "", "all")>
    <cfset ret = trim(ReReplaceNoCase(ret, "<[^>]*>", "", "ALL"))>
    <cfset ret = ReplaceList(ret, "À,Á,Â,Ã,Ä,Å,Æ,È,É,Ê,Ë,Ì,Í,Î,Ï,Ð,Ñ,Ò,Ó,Ô,Õ,Ö,Ø,Ù,Ú,Û,Ü,Ý,à,á,â,ã,ä,å,æ,è,é,ê,ë,ì,í,î,ï,ñ,ò,ó,ô,õ,ö,ø,ù,ú,û,ü,ý,&nbsp;,&amp;", "A,A,A,A,A,A,AE,E,E,E,E,I,I,I,I,D,N,O,O,O,O,O,0,U,U,U,U,Y,a,a,a,a,a,a,ae,e,e,e,e,i,i,i,i,n,o,o,o,o,o,0,u,u,u,u,y, , ")>
    <cfset ret = trim(rereplace(ret, "[[:punct:]]"," ","all"))>
    <cfset ret = rereplace(ret, "[[:space:]]+","!","all")>
    <cfset ret = ReReplace(ret, "[^a-zA-Z0-9!]", "", "ALL")>
    <cfset ret = trim(rereplace(ret, "!+", arguments.Spacer, "all"))>
    <cfreturn ret>
</cffunction>

<cfset stringToBeSlugged = "This is a string abcde àáâãäå èéêë ìíîï òóôö ùúûü ñ año ñññññññññññññ" />
<cfoutput>"#stringToBeSlugged# = #generateSlug(stringToBeSlugged)#</cfoutput>
```

**Support for more International Character**

If you want to widen your support for international characters, you could use ICU4J (java) and Paul Hastings' Transliterator.CFC to transliterate all of the characters and then replace any remaining spaces, dashes, slashes, etc with dashes.

https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/ec4617b066fc4bb601f620bc93bacb57

http://site.icu-project.org/download

After installing both, you can convert non-Latin characters by identifying the language id (to be converted to) and pass the string to be converted:

```
<cfset Transliterator = CreateObject("component","transliterator")>

<cfoutput>
<cfloop array="#TestStrings#" index="TestString">
<h3>TestString = "#TestString#"</h3>
<blockquote>
    <div>CFC-1 = #Transliterator.transliterate('Latin-ASCII', TestString)#</div>
    <div>CFC-2 = #Transliterator.transliterate('any-NFD; [:nonspacing mark:] any-remove; any-NFC', TestString)#</div>       
</blockquote>
<hr>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>

<h2>Available Language IDs</h2>
<cfdump var="#Transliterator.getAvailableIDs()#" label="Language IDs">
```